# Advantage of initialization variable to Hexadecimal

Tags: c++, hash, sha256, hash-function

I am working on a hash function coded in c++ and i was wondering why main constant variables are initialized with hex value. Like

```
unsigned long i= 0x428a2f98 ;
```

Is this done for the sake of performance if yes than please explain, because i think it have be converted to integer value at some point.

Comment: Sometimes, such as on embedded systems, the value assigned is an address of a hardware device.  Addresses on embedded systems are best viewed in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 5):

The way constants defined in the source code does not do anything for performance, as it will be converted to binary representation by compiler. It is there only for readability, for example binary data can be easier interpreted in hex than decimal notation.

Comment: @alihamza I have already said about redability, did I not? For debugging purpose it does not matter either, again this is compile time information, if you write `int i = 0x10;` or `int i = 16;` you will not see any difference at runtime.